# A phrase to describe someone's immediate liking toward some negative activity?

Tags: phrases

How to describe someone's immediate liking toward some negative activity?

For example, in the example below, I was told that "He took **an instant liking to** bullying" doesn't sound well:

> When this class had just been formed, it turned out that Jeffrey was a
>   head taller than anyone else in his class and much stronger at that.
>   He took **an instant liking to** bullying his classmates - as if it were
>   something natural for him. He has never stopped bullying his peers
>   until this day!

So what would be the right way then?

---

My question was edited. The previous title was: ""to take an instant liking to" something - is this phrase possible in English?"

Here is how my question looked before:

Can I use such an expression as "to take an instant liking to" to describe someone's liking toward some activity or a thing at the very first exposure?

For example,

> When this class had just been formed, it turned out that Jeffrey was a
>   head taller than anyone else in his class and much stronger at that.
>   He took **an instant liking to** bullying his classmates - as if it were
>   something natural for him. He has never stopped bullying his peers
>   until this day!

Comment: The expression is commonly used to mean exactly what it says but it does not sit comfortably in your sentence. We use it more often to refer to people or activities rather than bad or cruel tendencies.

Comment: @RonaldSole -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: From [Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20a%20liking%20to) **take a liking to** (idiom) - *to begin to like (someone or something).* Where ***instant*** just has its normal meaning, which can be easily seen as equivalent to M-W's example usage *She **took an immediate liking to sailing** when she tried it for the first time.*

Comment: A piece of information for the record: without "a liking", another idiom will appear--[take to someone/something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-to)--meaning the same (_I took to John immediately._)

Comment: Not only is **an instant liking to bullying** odd—It's like saying he took an instant liking to biting his fingernails— but your use  of **at that** is a tad off-kilter as well.  *Not only is this paint remover ineffective, it's far more expensive at that.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I don't see how the use of **at that** in my example is wrong and yours in your sentence about remover is right. Is it like **at that** only goes well with "Not only ..., but ..." construction?

Comment: @RonaldSole: "We use it more often to refer to people or activities rather than bad or cruel tendencies" - Will it go well with making jokes? (like "He took an instant liking to making jokes about that whole plan")

Comment: @brilliant That's awkward too and not idiomatic. Prefer **he liked** or **he enjoyed** making jokes.

Comment: @RonaldSole: "Prefer he liked or he enjoyed making jokes" - But how would you describe the fact that he not only liked or enjoyed but that he started enjoying that immediately, that is, as soon as he made his first try?

Comment: @brilliant: Why not ask about **at that** as a separate question?  My wife, who went to university in England and reads tons of British novels, tells me it's a BrE usage that is slightly different from AmE usage.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Just asked here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180302/how-is-at-that-used-in-british-and-american-english-in-the-end-of-sentences Not sure if I fomulated it well, though.