# How is "at that" used in British and American English in the end of sentences?

Tags: phrase-usage

Are there any rules on how "at that" should be used in the end of a sentence?

> Not only was he discriminatory, but even quite rude at that.
>
> He was very discriminatory and even quite rude at that.

Comment: There are some example sentences here: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/at-that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will speak for the way I hear it used in AmE ([central-atlantic](http://dare.wisc.edu/maps/regional-distributions) is my native dialect).

> Not only was this paint remover ineffective, it was the most expensive one on the shelf at that!

A synonym in AmE is "to boot".

> Not only was this paint remover ineffective, it was the most expensive one on the shelf to boot!

The emphasis underscores something that runs counter to the statement in the first clause.

P.S. I am told that in England it can mean "moreover" or "besides" without contrast with the prior assertion.

> He was a fine athlete and a superb marksman at that.

I *think* the underlying common meaning emphasizes something you might not have expected having heard the first assertion, but I'd like to have some input from BrE speakers. Would the following be a proper idiomatic usage?

> He was the biggest athlete on the team and the strongest at that.

My inclination is to say no, it isn't, but that this would be:

> He was the biggest athlete on the team and the speediest at that.

Comment: Are you sure that's restricted to BrE? I've usually heard it with the meaning of "moreover" with no prior statements it would run counter to. An AmE author writes: "That Kate could stand on her hearthstone and see the man at a distance was not surprising since her new home was **still only a frame and a somewhat rickety one at that**."; USA Today: "Purves later explained: it had been a warning sign, and a big one at that."; The New York Times: "The state's failure to show the impact of illegal immigration on schools was only a part of the decision, he said, and a nuanced one at that."

Comment: The LDOCE, to whose entry I linked under the question, would normally label the definitions as confined to a certain dialect, were that the case – and in this one they haven't. (Of course, no one is infallible, but I don't think they've made a mistake here.)

Comment: @userr2684291:  Those examples do seem to me to put a counterspin on the prior assertion. The frame is not the prototypical decent frame but a rickety one. The warning sign was not a run-of-the-mill warning but one that could have been placed in ALL CAPS! The decision was not an average one but a complicated and nuanced one. Do you find the marksman and strongest athlete examples I gave to be fully idiomatic in BrE? The phrase *superb marksman* seems a gratuitous addendum that could be paraphrased "not to mention a superb marksman"; *strongest* seems perfectly in line with the prior assertion.

Comment: Yes, none of these work for me for the reason you gave for the *superb marksman* one, and I asked one of my online friends from Australia, and they also don't like them. Sorry. (The last example sounded a little "better" to them but still off.) Don't really have any Brits handy at the moment, but I doubt they'll like it. The OED (2nd ed.) says about *at that*: "(orig. U.S., colloq. or slang): estimated at that rate, at that standard, even in that capacity, in respect of that; too; ‘into the bargain’: ‘a cant phrase..used to define more nearly or intensify something already said’ (Bartlett)."